# Split rows and assign values pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates, row, replicate

I have four a data frame as follows:

| Proxyid | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 456 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 789 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

This is the idea of the data frame. now I want to duplicate the rows where there are more than one 1. and assign values as follows.

| Proxyid | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 456 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 456 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 456 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 456 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 789 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I would really appreciate any input. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One option via `pd.get_dumies`:

```
df1 = (
    pd.get_dummies(
        df.set_index('Proxyid')
        .mul(df.columns[1:])
        .replace('', np.NAN)
        .stack()
    )
    .reset_index().drop('level_1', 1)
) 
result = df1.append(df[~df.Proxyid.isin(df1.Proxyid)])
```

OUTPUT:

|  | Proxyid | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 123 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 456 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 456 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 456 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 456 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 789 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

If you've extra columns just add them in `set_index` and use:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Proxyid', 'test'])
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df1.mul(df1.columns).replace('', np.NAN).stack()).reset_index()
result = df1.append(df[~df.Proxyid.isin(df1.Proxyid)])
```

Comment: I wanted to add what if I have more than those 5 columns? and I just want to operate on those mentioned columns?